# regex to extract words after ":"

Tags: python-3.x

what is the regex expresssion to extract the word after the specific keywords -

```
zones_list.txt
------------------------
VSAN:1     FCID:0xef3300
------------------------
port-wwn (vendor)           :21:33:00:02:ac:07:e9:ea             
node-wwn                    :2f:f7:00:02:ac:07:e9:ea
class                       :3
node-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
ipa                         :ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
fc4-types:fc4_features      :scsi-fcp:both 
symbolic-port-name          :4UW0002976 - 1:3:3 - LPE32004-32G
symbolic-node-name          :HPE_3PAR C650 - 4UW0002976 - fw:4300
port-type                   :N 
port-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
fabric-port-wwn             :20:16:8c:60:4f:63:bb:f0
hard-addr                   :0x000000
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00             
connected interface         :fc1/22
switch name (IP address)    :c3-cs9148-06 (15.112.40.103)
------------------------
VSAN:1     FCID:0xef3500
------------------------


port-wwn (vendor)           :10:00:00:90:fa:a0:4f:aa (Emulex)    
node-wwn                    :20:00:00:90:fa:a0:4f:aa
class                       :3
node-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
ipa                         :ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
fc4-types:fc4_features      :
symbolic-port-name          :
symbolic-node-name          :
port-type                   :N 
port-ip-addr                :0.0.0.0
fabric-port-wwn             :20:06:8c:60:4f:63:bb:f0
hard-addr                   :0x000000
permanent-port-wwn (vendor) :00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00             
connected interface         :fc1/6
switch name (IP address)    :c3-cs9148-06 (15.112.40.103)


with open('zones_list.txt') as fin:
    for line in islice(dropwhile(lambda L: '10:00:00:00:c9:b5:63:45' not in L, fin), 1, 15, 1):
        #print(line)
        if 'connected interface | switch name (IP address) ' in line:
        print(line)
```

I open a file and extract the next 15 lines in the match using the dropwhile() expression.
Questions:
From this data I want to extact what the connected interface value is and what the switch name value is?
Q1:Can i use a OR expression within the if statement instead of elsif?
Q2:And how to print the word after "connected interface    :" and word after 'switch name (IP address)    :"?

help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the entire file into a single string, and then use `re.findall`:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\b(VSAN:\d+\s+\FCID:\S+).*?\b(connected interface\s+:\S+).*?(\bswitch name \(IP address\)\s+:\S+)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
for match in matches:
    print(match[0] + '\n' + match[1] + '\n' + match[2])
```

Given your input above, this script prints:

```
VSAN:1     FCID:0xef3300
connected interface         :fc1/22
switch name (IP address)    :c3-cs9148-06
VSAN:1     FCID:0xef3500
connected interface         :fc1/6
switch name (IP address)    :c3-cs9148-06
```

Comment: Thanks for the pattern Tim - >(r'\b(VSAN:\d+\s+\FCID:\S+).*?\b(connected interface\s+:\S+). I need to extract only data after the ":" sign? zone_list is the big list and i want the values for swich name and interface which appears after the port wwn. Hence i have extracted just the 15 lines using the first for loop (dropwhile()).

Comment: @redpy If you want to isolate only the interface and switch values, then just change the capture groups in my pattern.  Yes, just use `:(\S+)` for both rows.